# Yet another WiFi performance issue

Tags: 16.10, iwlwifi

Got a faster internet today so decided to test it and ... figured out that I have the same 20-30 Mbps out of 50, when wired.

I tried to play with channels, as I found that there are multiple neighbors running wifi on the same channel. It didn't give any significant and stable result. It could even drop below numbers I mentioned.

I tried to use a router from a provider and also attached another router to it. Both show the same performance. I tried also to play with modes and leave only 802.11n without any significant result either.

EDIT1: Here is a link to the wireless-info output http://paste.ubuntu.com/23671497

EDIT2: Tried to disable 11n, speed dropped 2 times, so didn't help. Didn't notice if swcrypto gives any drawbacks/benefits. I also noticed that Cisco router in 11n only mode works 50% faster and gives me about 30Mbps

```
##### lspci #############################
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N  2230 [8086:0887] (rev c4)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN [8086:4062]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"F62Q7"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'F62Q7' [AC1]>   
      Bit Rate=43.3 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=65/70  Signal level=-45 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:237   Missed beacon:0
```

So, the question is - if it's possible to achieve higher speed than the current one?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the *whole* result? In the past https://paste.ubuntu.com/ and http://pastebin.com/ have worked fine as laid out in the top answer. You can even paste and fit the whole result inline into your question. Thanks.

Comment: Try `11n_disable=8` to enable aggressive TX

Comment: Thank you, @Jeremy31, it gave me better upload. Down speed is still the same.

Comment: It's interesting, people marked the question as duplicate, but solutions provided didn't work for me. I'm at the point where I started thinking that it can be a problem of a too noisy frequency. Could it be the case?